# Local backup bash

Tags: bash

The following code copy a complete folder (that has 3 folders inside), then check if errors are generated and send email if there's errors, the it proceeds to create 3 different tar files and finally move this tar files to a mounted network drive, every name has been changed or somehow altered in order to comply with my company security policy.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

readonly SUBJECT="BACKUP"
readonly TO="mail@domain.com"
readonly MESSAGE="~/backupMessageError.txt"
readonly TOALL="mail1@domain.com, mail2@domain.com"
readonly MESSAGEALL="~/backupMessageSuccess.txt"

backup () {
    if grep -qs '/mount/dir/' /proc/mounts; then
        rsync --exclude /a/folder/ -ravz /backup/source /backup/destination/ 2> ~/backupMessageError.txt
        if checker $1; then
            mail
        else
            compression
        fi
    else
        mount -o hard,nolock IP:/volume1/folder /mount/dir/ 2> ~/backupMessageError.txt
        if checker $1; then
            mail
        else
            rsync --exclude /a/folder/ -ravz /backup/source/ /backup/destination/ 2>> ~/backupMessageError.txt
            if checker $1; then
                mail
            else
                compression
            fi
        fi
    fi
}

compression (){
    tar -I pigz -cf backupFolder1.tar.gz folder1 2>> ~/backupMessageError.txt
    tar -I pigz -cf backupFolder2.tar.gz folder2 2>> ~/backupMessageError.txt
    tar -I pigz -cf backupFolder3.tar.gz folder3 2>> ~/backupMessageError.txt
    if checker $1; then
        mail
    else
        storage
    fi
}

storage (){
    mv /a/folder/backupFolder1.tar.gz /mount/dir/ 2>> ~/backupMessageError.txt
    mv /a/folder/backupFolder2.tar.gz /mount/dir/ 2>> ~/backupMessageError.txt
    mv /a/folder/backupFolder3.tar.gz /mount/dir/ 2>> ~/backupMessageError.txt
    if checker $1; then
        mail
    fi
}

checker (){
    if [ "$(wc -l < ~/backupMessageError.txt)" -ge 1 ];then
       return 0;
    else
       return 1;
    fi
}

mail () {
    if checker $1;then
        mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$TO" < $MESSAGE
    else
        mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$TOALL" < $MESSAGEALL
    fi
}
backup
```

Comment: Welcome to CR. Are the folder names completely different in the uncensored version or is it like folder1, folder2, .. (A repeatable pattern)?

Comment: Folders have completely different names. Thank you for welcoming me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What is `$1` ?

All the functions except `checker` include a call `checker $1`.
But none of those functions are called with a parameter,
so `$1` is never actually defined.
The only function that is called with a parameter is `checker`,
but it doesn't actually use a parameter.

As such, you could remove all the `$1` without changing the behavior of the program.

More importantly, when you want to use `$1` for something,
it's good to assign it to a variable with a descriptive name.
That way the reader can understand the purpose.
In the current program it's hard to tell if `$1` is simple negligence and oversight,
or a bug waiting to explode.
If it had a descriptive name, I could make a more educated guess.

#### Always quote variables used in command parameters

Instead of `checker $1` always write `checker "$1"`.

#### Checking if a file is empty

`checker` checks if a file is empty by counting lines.
A simpler way exists using the `[ -s ... ]` builtin:

```
checker() {
    [ -s ~/backupMessageError.txt ]
}
```

Notice that there's no need to write `if [ -s ... ]; then return 0; else return 1; fi`,
since the exit code of a function is the exit code of the last command,
so we can simply use the command without the `if-else`.

#### Use better names

The current function names don't help understand what the program is doing.
In fact they are all *nouns*, when the natural choice would be *verbs*, or *questions*.
For example `checker` checks if there were any errors.
A more natural naming would be `seenAnyErrors`.
Notice how the code could read like prose:

```
if seenAnyErrors; then
    sendErrorReport
else
    createBackups
fi
```

#### Improve error handling

The current error handling is not so good. Let's take a closer look at for example:

> ```
> tar -I pigz -cf backupFolder1.tar.gz folder1 2>> ~/backupMessageError.txt
> tar -I pigz -cf backupFolder2.tar.gz folder2 2>> ~/backupMessageError.txt
> tar -I pigz -cf backupFolder3.tar.gz folder3 2>> ~/backupMessageError.txt
>
> if seenAnyErrors; then ...; fi
> ```

What if the first `tar` command fails?
Is your intention to continue with the others anyway?

The current way of checking for errors expects that a failing command writes something to `stderr`. That's not necessarily the case always, therefore it would be fragile to rely on that. A more reliable way is using the exit code.

A better way to write the above, relying on exit code, would be:

```
failures=0

tar -I pigz -cf backupFolder1.tar.gz folder1 2>> "$errors"
((failures += $?))

tar -I pigz -cf backupFolder2.tar.gz folder2 2>> "$errors"
((failures += $?))

tar -I pigz -cf backupFolder3.tar.gz folder3 2>> "$errors"
((failures += $?))

if [ "$failures" != 0 ]; then ...; fi
```

#### Don't double-quote `~`

I believe this is an error:

> ```
> readonly MESSAGE="~/backupMessageError.txt"
> ```

When `~` is double-quoted, the shell won't expand it to `$HOME`.
As it is, I think the command `mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$TO" < $MESSAGE` will fail with "No such file or directory" error. That variable definition should have been written as:

```
readonly MESSAGE=~/backupMessageError.txt
```